# Ruby C-Style Comment on Documentation

Tags: ruby, comments

I found in Ruby's documentation that [C-style comments are supported](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/_lib/racc/rdoc/grammar_en_rdoc.html#label-Comment):

> You can insert comment about all places. Two style comment can be used, Ruby style (#.….) and C style ( .….. ) .

Does this mean that Ruby supports `/*` and `*/`? When I try it, it comes with an error:

```
target of repeat operator is not specified: /*
test
*/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a grammar for Ruby, but a grammar for Racc (a Ruby equivalent of yacc). Just like yacc files are not C, Racc files are not Ruby.